# Difference between diff and abs_diff in openCL

Tags: opencl

this may be silly question but yet i am unable to figure it out...

syntax of abs and abs_diff is
    ugentype abs (gentype x)
    ugentype abs_diff (gentype x,gentype y)

let's take x=-4 and y=3

```
is there any difference between abs(-4-3)  and abs_diff(-4,3)  the result
```

of both operation is same... if i can rewrite abs_diff as abs then 
why khronos gave 2 abs function

thank you

Answer (score 4):

According to [abs, abs_diff man](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/abs.html):

- abs returns |x|.
- abs_diff returns |x-y| **without modulo overflow**.

Comment: In addition, these methods typically map to a HW feature/instruction. So if it is possible and matches your use case, use abs_diff().

Answer (score 0):

abs(-4-3) = abs(-7) = 7

abs(-4, 3) = abs(-4 - 3) = abs(-7) = 7

there are two functions for convenience depending on which you think will be more consice for what you are doing.